# Select clause result as comparison expression

Tags: sql, database

In Sql queries can I use the result of a select clause using aggregate functions as an expression for a comparison?

For example:

```
HAVING COUNT(a) = SELECT COUNT(b) FROM c WHERE b=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  You just need parentheses as you would with any subquery:

```
HAVING COUNT(a) = (SELECT COUNT(b) FROM c WHERE b=1)
```

Note that `count(b)` is not necessary when you know that `b` is not `NULL`.  There is no need to check for `NULL` values, so:

```
HAVING COUNT(a) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM c WHERE b = 1)
```